# Update a Chosen multiple select field with a localStorage variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, jquery-chosen

i have a Chosen multiple select field and i save the choices of the user in localstorage.language_request. When the user come back i need tu update the field with the previous choices.

My JS to save the choices selected by the user:

```
$('.calcul_checkout').on("change keyup", function(){
  var language_request_brut = $('#language_request').val();
  var language_request = [];
  jQuery.each(language_request_brut, function(i, val){
          language_request.push(val)
 });
  localStorage.language_request = language_request;
}
```

My JS when the user return on the page and i need to update the Chosen field with the choices selected previously

```
if (localStorage.language_request != null){ 
 $("#language_request").val(localStorage.language_request).trigger("chosen:updated");
}
```

The Chosen field (in Rails):

```
<span>
 <%= select_tag(:language_request, options_for_select([['Français', 'FR'],
  ['Anglais', 'EN'],
  ['Italien', 'IT'],
  class:"answer language_request calcul_checkout chosen-select", multiple: true) %>
</span>
```

**The problem,** localStorage.language_request is equal to ["FR,EN"]. It's save all the choices into one string. And to update the Chosen field i need  to format this array into ["FR","EN"] (one string by choice).

Comment: Have you thought about simply splitting the string?

Comment: Good idea @scriptify i tried and apparently it's working. I will make some tests to be sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to update my code like this with the split methode:

```
if (localStorage.language_request != null){
      $("#language_request").val(localStorage.language_request.split(",")).trigger("chosen:updated");
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here, you need to change code from

```
$('.calcul_checkout').on("change keyup", function(){
  var language_request_brut = $('#language_request').val();
  var SelectedLanguage = language_request_brut.split(",");
  var language_request = [];
  for(i=0;i<SelectedLanguage.length;i++) 
  {
          language_request.push(SelectedLanguage[i])
  }
  localStorage.language_request = language_request;
}
```

This will help you because $('#language_request').val()  function returns value as "FR,EN" and you push it directly.So spiting string will help you.

Comment: Thank you, I have this error with your code `Uncaught TypeError: language_request_brut.split is not a function`